# Vim autocomplete: Cancelling autocomplete popup

Tags: vim, autocomplete

If I hit ctrl+n in vim, I'll get a list of suggested autocomplete options in a popup box.

This is fine...but if I decide I don't want to autocomplete after all, I'm not quite sure what to press to revert the suggestion.

For example, suppose I type `rea`, hit ctrl+n, and autocomplete pops up with `really_long_method_name_damn_this_is_annoying`...and I don't want that. I can't quite figure out how to revert the syntax back to just `rea`... I have to manually delete the unwanted characters.

I'm guessing this is a pretty straightforward thing, but still - if anyone knows how, please let me know.

Comment: Ha, +1 for both a good question and a better method name :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will end the current completion and put back that originally typed text.

See

```
:h complete_CTRL-E
:h ins-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing `Ctrl+P` to take you back to the original (or if you are feeling ambitious, `Ctrl+N` until you loop back around :) ).

Comment: well, if I press `CTRL-N` _n_ times, I have to press `CTRL-P` _n+1_ times to get me back to original...

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The former will remove the autocompleted text, and the latter will close the popup.

Comment: It also exits inset mode.

Comment: This answer assumes that there is only one suggestion in the popup. Otherwise you need to hit Ctrl+P as many times as there are suggestions which is annoying. Ctrl+E is the correct answer

Comment: ..this is what I did until today I finally seeked salvation on this issue and found Peter Rincker's hint at CTRL+P above.. oh my, all these lost years xD

Answer (score 1):

Type `:help ins-completion-menu` for a detailed description of all your options.